# Material colour in BGE is different

Tags: game-engine

I highlighted the colour that i would like to get and the 
colour on my loading screen in BGEngine. They are different!
 is it possible to have the same colour as from material panel?
Followed the advice of Crantisz, but still have  another colour (2nd screenshot)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you have different color - is shading. Shading model adds shadows and specular to the model, so color changes.

If you set material shading to **shadless**, and **viewport shading** display mode to **Material**, you will get exact same color as you set to diffuse.

[image]